# Problemas con sweetalert2 - Angular // A rest parameter must be of an array type

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, npm, sweetalert2

Hola amigos tengo un problema con mi proyecto angular y es que no puedo hacer mi paquete para producción porque el **sweetalert2** me salta este error

> ERROR in node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts(23,19): error
>   TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>       node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts(361,41): error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
>       node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts(361,50): error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
>       node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts(361,59): error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.

y no he podido saltarlo alguna idea de como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema es debido a que estás usando una versión de Typescript antigua (versión 2), pero la sintaxis usada por sweetalert es aceptada a partir de Typescript 3

Comment: mmm ok voy a revisar esto

Answer (score 0):

Hola si no lo has resuelto, modifica el archivo node_modules -> sweetalert2 -> sweetalert2.d.ts ->

(línea 23 aprox)
Sustituye:
function fire(...options: SweetAlertArrayOptions): Promise;
por:
function swal(settings: SweetAlertOptions & { useRejections?: false }): Promise;

(línea 364 aprox)
Sustituye:
export type SweetAlertArrayOptions = [string?, string?, SweetAlertType?];
Por:
export type SweetAlertArrayOptions = [string] | [string, string] | [string, string, string];

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

En aquel entonces no pude solucionar pero lo que hice fue abrir el paquete de sweetalert2 y comentar la funcion fire

```
function fire() {}
```

e instalar sweetalert normal para asi poder usar el mixin de sweetalert2 y los alert nomal con sweetalert.

luego con mas tiempo reviso que paso.

Gracias a todos...